# Can I encapsulate wcf proxy close() in a destructor?

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have a WCF application.

I understand that the best practice is to use these client proxy objects with either a **using** statement or **try/finally** block like this:

```
using(var proxy = MyChannelFactory.CreateChannel())
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

**or**

```
var proxy = MyChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
try
{
    //do stuff here
}finally{
    proxy.close();
}
```

What I'm wondering is this.... 
If I put the code to close down the channel in the destructor, can I rely on the Garbage Collector to call the destructor code once the proxy object goes out of scope, and thereby make sure that the proxies all get shut down properly?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to call Close() on the proxy in a finally block.

The proxy derives ultimately from `ICommunicationObject`, and calling [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520.aspx) can throw further exceptions.

Rather than calling Close(), call [Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.abort.aspx):

```
finally
{
    proxy.Abort();
}
```

This will close the proxy safely.

Additionally, I don't see any reason to force the GC to collect your proxy - GC has already been optimized to work in the most efficient manner, so don't interfere with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to not rely on the garbage collector to do the job. You don't know when garbage collection is going to happen and it may not happen for a time longer that you would expect. In that time, you will be holding on to your open proxy.

using and try/finally are easy to use and follow the rule that you should close resources as soon as you finish working with them.

Comment: Disagree, the rule is you should dispose *non-managed* resources as soon as you have finished with them.